# TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly 2 arguments (2 given) TypeError? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have the following function defined:

```
def eigval(matrix):
    a = matrix[0, 0]
    b = matrix[0, 1]
    c = matrix[1, 0]
    d = matrix[1, 1]
    c1 = (a + d) + sqrt((4 * b * c) + ((a - d)**2))
    c2 = (a + d) - sqrt((4 * b * c) + ((a - d)**2))
    return c1 / 2, c2 / 2
```

It is created to find the eigenvalues of a 2 X 2 matrix. I am using it to iteratively run the Jacobi algorithm on a matrix. The matrix passed in is a dictionary that uses tuples as keys to represent the position and floats as values. This function will work fine for about 6 iterations, but then I will get a:

```
TypeError: __getitem__() takes exactly 2 arguments (2 given)
```

on the first line of the block (the one with the a).

I am completely confused by this because like I said, it works fine for about 6 runs and then stops.

EDIT: Here's a function that creates the kind of matrix I would pass in:
(Given that the matrix will be different for each iteration)

```
def create():
    matrix = {}
    matrix[0, 0] = 2
    matrix[0, 1] = 1
    matrix[1, 0] = 1
    matrix[1, 1] = 2
    return matrix
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! (P.S. first post here)

Comment: Yup, tuples are the keys to the dictionary. Thanks for the quick response. I just don't understand how it can work 6 times and then stop like this

Comment: It's helpful to give a complete example - one we can actually run to test (give us a bit of sample data that shows the problem).

Comment: Can you show us a sample matrix? I don't see where in this code it would fail, so it may be somewhere outside of it.

Comment: You would better try catch the error, and print the matrix with error.

Comment: Sample matrix added. I will try and catch the matrix

Comment: So I caught the error and from what I can tell, after some iterations, the matrix turns into an empty string. (when I print it there is a blank; I can concatenate other strings onto it as well as call functions on it). I have no ideas why this is happening.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, you must have modified the matrix somewhere else. You can print out the following to see if it's really a string: `print(type(matrix))`. It should be a dictionary, going by your constructor. Can you show us the code of the loop you are using?

Comment: Sure enough it turned up as a str. I would post my code, but I don't want to waste any more of your time. It would require some knowledge of the Jacobi algorithm, plus I'm not really sure how to post all of my code here. I really really appreciate the help though. The community here seems fantastic

Comment: Well, a) I do know the algorithm and b) even if I didn't, I can see where and how objects are modified even if I didn't know. It's up to you, but don't be afraid of asking questions like these. A simple way to debug is to print out the type of the matrix after every step inside the loop, along with the iteration number and some information on where precisely in the loop it is. Then you'll see exactly where the matrix will be changed, which will hopefully make it easier to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is a dict using tuples as keys, this is probably not what you want to do.

Try using nested lists:

```
from math import sqrt

def create():
    matrix = [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
    return matrix

def eigval(matrix):
    a = matrix[0][0]
    b = matrix[1][0]
    c = matrix[0][1]
    d = matrix[1][1]
    c1 = (a + d) + sqrt((4 * b * c) + ((a - d)**2))
    c2 = (a + d) - sqrt((4 * b * c) + ((a - d)**2))
    return [c1 / 2, c2 / 2]

>>> m = create() 
>>> eigval(m)
[3.0, 0.0]
```

Or alternatively use numpy:

```
import numpy

def eigval(matrix):
    a = matrix[0, 0]
    b = matrix[1, 0]
    c = matrix[0, 1]
    d = matrix[1, 1]
    c1 = (a + d) + sqrt((4 * b * c) + ((a - d)**2))
    c2 = (a + d) - sqrt((4 * b * c) + ((a - d)**2))
    return numpy.array([c1 / 2, c2 / 2])

>>> m = numpy.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
>>> m
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
>>> eigvalues, eigvectors = numpy.linalg.eig(m)
>>> eigvalues
array([ 0.,  3.])

>>> eigval(m)
array([ 3.,  0.])
```